# How to read GetDeviceCaps() return values?

Tags: windows

I am new to Windows API and I just can't seem to figure this out:

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getdevicecaps) the function `int GetDeviceCaps(HDC hdc,int index);` returns integer values which correspond to the selected item I want to know about. However, how am I supposed to convert the integers to the values?

```
printf("Rastercaps: %d\n", GetDeviceCaps(hdc, RASTERCAPS));
// rastercaps: 32409
```

item RASTERCAPS:

values

- RC_BANDING   Requires banding support.
- RC_BITBLT    Capable of transferring bitmaps.
- RC_BITMAP64  Capable of supporting bitmaps larger than 64 KB.
- RC_DI_BITMAP Capable of supporting the SetDIBits and GetDIBits
  functions.
- RC_DIBTODEV  Capable of supporting the SetDIBitsToDevice
  function.
- RC_FLOODFILL Capable of performing flood fills.

...

Does 32409 mean the device has RASTERCAP values (capabilities) 3,2,4,0 and 9, in the order as stated in their table?

Thank you.

Comment: This is a bit field so you have to use binary! 32409 = 111111010011001b, so the bits with values 1, 8, 16, 128, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, and 16384 are set. To see if a particular bit it set, use the "and" operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're bitmasks. In the relevant C header file (wingdi.h) there is

```
/* Raster Capabilities */
#define RC_NONE
#define RC_BITBLT           1       /* Can do standard BLT.             */
#define RC_BANDING          2       /* Device requires banding support  */
#define RC_SCALING          4       /* Device requires scaling support  */
#define RC_BITMAP64         8       /* Device can support >64K bitmap   */
```

...and many more.

The return value (32409) is made up of the bitwise-or of these values. So, for example, if you wanted to know if the device could support >64K  bitmap you would do

```
int rc = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, RASTERCAPS);
if (rc & RC_BITMAP64) { /* it does support >64k */ }
```

So in this case, 32409 is 0111111010011001 in binary which means it has the capabilities RC_BITBLT | RC_BITMAP64 | RC_GDI20_OUTPUT | RC_DI_BITMAP | 
RC_DIBTODEV | RC_BIGFONT | RC_STRETCHBLT | RC_FLOODFILL | RC_STRETCHDIB | RC_OP_DX_OUTPUT.

See ["Bitwise operations in C"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C)